# Как передать в jquery ajax post переменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

При передаче переменных в `ajax` запросе методом пост не передается переменная `ntext`. Вот `js` обработчик

```
$('#save_new').on('click',function( event ){
    var nid = $('#id_new').val();
    //alert(nid);
    var tle = $('#ntitle').val();
    //alert(tle);
    var elm = tinyMCE.get('ntext').getContent();
    //alert(elm);
    var posting =    $.post('/admin/template/news/news_ajax.php','act=add_new&ntitle='+tle+'&ntext='+elm+'&id_new='+nid);
    console.log(posting);
    posting.done(function( data ) {
     //alert( "done success" );
            if(data){
               // alert( "data is" );
        var ndata = JSON.parse( data ); 
                 alert( data );
    $('#table-new tbody').html(ndata.res);
    set_new();
            }
    });

    //$('form#f_new')[0].reset();
    $("#add_new").modal('hide');

});
```

В консоли видно и в алертах, что в `data` отсутствует все что касается `ntext`, хотя перед отправкой эту переменную успешно из `tinymce` получаю. Надо сказать, что в этот код работает и в `php` успешно добавляется в базу все как надо. Проблема в том, что в `data` отсутствует переменная `ntext` и при обновлении строки она туда не вставляется. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибаюсь, я уже голову сломал.

Comment: там серверная сторона его и не возвращает, скорее всего.

Comment: а что у вас хранится в переменной elm?

Comment: в переменной elm хранится данные из textarea, к которой подключен текстовый редактор tinymce

Answer (score 1):

Через `console.log` проверь что возвращает

```
var elm = tinyMCE.get('ntext').getContent();
```

А вообще советую использовать вот так:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: path,
      data: { act: "add_new", ntitle: tle, ntext: elm, id_new: nid }
          type: "POST",
          success: function(response){
          //Работа с response
        }
  });
```

Используя

```
function add_new(){}
```

возможно теряются или затираются значения из $_POST, лучше передавать их в функцию

```
function add_new($post){}
```

Comment: var elm возвращает то, что в textarea лежит. Скажите data это ведь отправляемое на сервер? Вот в data нет этой переменной, но зато на сервер доходит...

Comment: @ZaurK не пойму, как может не быть в data, а на сервер приходить? Откуда тогда он на сервере берется?) elm хранит в себе строку? если да, то на сервер должно приходить вот это    $_POST["elm"]

Comment: Исправил код в ответе, может так будет понятнее

Comment: Переделал как вы написали через ajax, ситуация такая же, на сервере в базу добавляется все нормально, но в data нет этой переменной...странно очень

Comment: @ZaurK Покажите код файла на сервере, так тяжело понять.

Comment: function add_new(){ global $db;
    $id_n = intval(str_replace('tr_','',$_POST['id_new']));
    if($id_n > 0){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE news SET title=?s, text=?s WHERE id=?i";
    $db->query($sql,$_POST['ntitle'],$_POST['ntext'],$id_n);
    //return list_n();   
    } 
    else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `news`(dt, title, text) VALUES (?i,?s,?s)";
    $db->query($sql,time(),$_POST['ntitle'],$_POST['ntext']);
    //return list_n();
    }

}

Comment: Как тут в комментариях форматировать код не пойму что-то

Comment: На сервере у тебя происходит return list_n(); а что она делает? json_encode()?

Comment: я сначала думал в return_list_n проблема, начал его менять - изменения не отражались никак,  потом вообще закомментировал. А так она по идее из базы выводит строчки для таблицы.

Comment: Проблема была в неправильном указании пути /admin/template/news/news_ajax.php - я тут оказывается старый файл подключал. Спасибо за комменты!